# Copy all nested tables in word document and paste them in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Need a sample to copy nested tables from a Word document to Excel

I have a sample code to select regular tables but not with nested tables

Or is there any way to copy all tables with specific rows and columns and paste them into an Excel document

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In this case there are two tables in the document, and in the second table cell(3,1) there is a nested table with 3 rows and 6 columns.
The code copy the nested table to ActiveSheet Range("A17") expanded.

```
Sub tabcop()

Set wb = GetObject(, "Word.Application").Activedocument
 wb.tables(2).cell(3, 1).tables(1).Range.Copy
Range("a17").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

This is the result in Excel

[image]